# Add favicon to elm webpage

Tags: favicon, elm

I use The Elm Architecture and my view-function is simply `div [] [...]`.

How to alter the view-function (or other functions) such that the favicon-link tag `<link rel="favicon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"  />` (or similar) gets generated into the index.html document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile elm src into javascript and load it from html.

when building:

```
elm-make src/Main.elm --output elm.js
```

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="favicon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"  />
  <script src="elm.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works.  elm-live will inject hot-reloading logic into the served html.

Comment: Thank you, for those who wonder: The command is
`elm-live src/Main.elm --output elm.js`